# How to define encode type?

Tags: decode, encode

i need to parse data from other site but its encoded.

```
<div style="height: 250px" data-highchart="yes" data-encoded="@7JyYoFmc0JiO7JCd5BXZ}iojIhJXZhJSfsICbldWZuRmI6snIl5WYixWZkJiOmFGbzVWfsIyclJXalNnI*6s1ei4WYtVmI6ISQkZXYuRXYnVmIsIyYvx2byJiOiMSOyEUNyUjIsIibldWY@0lmdlN0bs9mciojIjMkMzMkMBJCLiYWasx2TwF2YpRXeioDMuQDLiQHayV2c]o9GbkJiOw4CMsICbp5WZXlGZ0hmI6QDLiQWY0FmI6s1W2ADL4cTXssVMyADL#tEDO30FLbFDOwwyNx0FLbJDNwwSL0kTXss1MwADLxUTNdxyWzYDMscTOy0FL]bRjMwwyM1cTXssFN4ADLxkjMz0FLbVDNwwSMwQTMdxyW2ADMsEDOyUTXsslN&amp;2ADLzMjNx0FLbdjMwwCNxIDNdxyW3gDMsUjNwYTXssFO0ADL1gDM20FLblDM#wwyN1YTOdxyW5YDMskTN3MTXssVMwIDMskDMwgTXssVMwgDMskzN5YTXssVM*xQDMsEDMykDOdxyWxIDMwwSM2ADO40FLbFjM2ADLyATO5MTXdxiItFmcrVmc&amp;iozeiUmbhJGblRmI6YWYsNXZ91XXsISZ4RnchNnI6snI4FEepNnRvJXbhRnI#6ICZ1JXY0l2buJCLiQ3bvxGdpBnRvJXbhRnI6ICdlFWbBRmdh5GdhdWZi0Xf" data-annotated="true"></div>
```

What type of encode was used and how can i decode this? Thanks!